# Replacing NaN values with desired values in one column according to class (1,2,3) in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `fillna()` function to replace `NaN` values in "Age" column according to given class in "Pclass" column. The code I'm using run successfully without any error, however, there is no change in the dataset. The same `NaN` values are present there. My code is given below.

```
train_data['Age'][train_data['Pclass']==1].fillna(38, inplace=True)
train_data['Age'][train_data['Pclass']==2].fillna(29, inplace=True)
train_data['Age'][train_data['Pclass']==3].fillna(24, inplace=True)
```

Comment: You are `fillna`ing on the slice of your original dataset.

Comment: Any other recommended way for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are filling na on a slice of dataset. So despite using `inplace`, the original dataset won't be changed.

One way using just for loop:

```
# train_data
   Age  Pclass
0  NaN       1
1  NaN       2
2  NaN       3

for p, v in zip([1,2,3], [38, 29, 24]):
    train_data.loc[train_data["Pclass"].eq(p), "Age"] = train_data.loc[train_data["Pclass"].eq(p), "Age"].fillna(v)
print(train_data)
```

Output:

```
    Age  Pclass
0  38.0       1
1  29.0       2
2  24.0       3
```